# Remove selected item count from ng-multiselect-dropdown in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, ng-multiselect-dropdown

I'm working on an Angular 8 web app. I have used ng-multiselect-dropdown for showing the city names. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Please see the implementation code below:

**HTML**

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
                      [placeholder]="'Cities'"
                      [data]="itemchild.userAllCities"
                      [settings]="dropdownSettings"
                    >
                    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

**TS**

```
this.dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: "Name",
      textField: "Name",
      itemsShowLimit: 0,
      enableCheckAll: false,
    };
```

I need to remove the selected item count from the multi-select dropdown. How can I do that?
Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Hi Vignesh, I am also facing the same issue, Did u get any solution for this?